# Inheritance and Overriding. How it differs in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, virtual, overriding

One thing i need to be clear. When using inheritance i can override a method without using any virtual or override keyword. My program also running and giving correct output. Then why do we have override concept even though we have inheritance. How it differs?

here is my code

```
class InheritanceDemo
{
public void Mymeth()
{
Console.WriteLine("this is base");
}
}

class A1 : InheritanceDemo
{

public void Mymeth()
{

Console.WriteLine("this is derived");
}
}
```

Main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

InheritanceDemo a = new A1();
A1 b = new A1();
a.Mymeth();
b.Mymeth();

}
```

output:

this is base

this is derived

Comment: Declare `b` as `InheritanceDemo` instead of `A1` (`InheritanceDemo b = new A1();`) and you'll get it.

Answer (score 0):

Function overriding is  needed when the derived class function has to do more or different job than the base class function.

These concepts becomes important in large scale application where problem is big so, u first create an abstract class (which just gives the ideas about how things might be rather than the direct implementation). These Abstract class can contain virtual methods (member functions) that any member of group working on has to implement (as virtual methods have to be defined in the derived class). 
I think u got my point... :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think the output is "correct"? With inheritance you want to call the correct **inherited** function and **not** a method in your base class. And that's what you define with virtual/override.

Comment: Yes i got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you compiled this you should have got a warning [CS0108](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0108).

Do not ignore warnings. Indeed, if you can set your compilation to error rather than warn. Warnings are generally a sign that you've done something bad or at best unclear. They aren't errors because you might have a good reason for doing something that looks bad or unclear at first look, but in the case of hiding instead of overriding we have `new`.

What you have here is not an override, though as you seem to expect, generally what you would want here is an override. That's part of why this code produces a compiler warning.

> My program also running and giving correct output

Maybe it's correct, but it's not correct if you expected an override. If it was overriding you should have "this is derived" output by both.

If it is correct, it's a bad design, because people generally expect overrides. You can stop the warning by changing `A1.Mymeth` to be defined as `public new void Mymeth()` which is a way to flag "I really meant to do this thing that looks wrong", but if you have to explain yourself, that's a bad sign. Hiding methods is generally only to be done when someone changing a base class under you forces your hand, you need to match names due to some sort of interoperability and a small number of other very rare cases.